# Display a default image if not exist in the database does not work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show an default image, if an image are not stored in database. Then only show the image stored in database. How can I solve this proble? Thanks

conecta.php

```
<? ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
$oConni=new mysqli('localhost','****','****','****');
$oConni->set_charset('utf8');
?>
```

images.php

```
<?php
   require('conecta.php');
   $stmt=$oConni->prepare("SELECT IMAGEN_IMAGENES FROM IMAGENES WHERE ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS=?");
   $stmt->bind_param('i',$_GET['idPrdOfr']);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   $stmt->bind_result($foto);
   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
     echo $foto;
   }
?>
```

search.php

```
function pintaImagen($id_prod_ofertados){
      $pintaImg=null;
      require ('conecta.php');
      $xSQL="SELECT IMAGEN_IMAGENES FROM IMAGENES WHERE ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS=?"; 
      $stmt = $oConni->prepare($xSQL) or die($oConni->error);
      $stmt->bind_param('i',$id_prod_ofertados);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($imagen);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        if (isset( $imagen )){
            $pintaImg.="<img class='img' src='images.php?idPrdOfr=" . $id_prod_ofertados . "' />";
        }
        else{

            $pintaImg.="<img class='img' src='images/none.png' />";
             //$pintaImg;
        }
        return $pintaImg;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Where is $imagen being set?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie See the `bind_result` call before `fetch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it needs to be this way:

```
if ($stmt->fetch() && isset( $imagen )) {
    $pintaImg.="<img class='img' src='images.php?idPrdOfr=" . $id_prod_ofertados . "' />";
} else {
    $pintaImg.="<img class='img' src='images/none.png' />";
    //$pintaImg;
}
return $pintaImg;
```

instead of the while loop in `search.php`.